# implement a comparer function that works to different classes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, design-patterns

Is there a way to implement a comparer function that can be used by several different classes, if not what about different classes with same member name? is there a design pattern for that?

ok,
I have several classes in some of them I have member with same name and type
I can implement(VB) Icomparer or IComparable for each class i.e. Class A:Implements IComparable and implement CompareTo function for each class (and I have lots of classes)
is there a way to implement one function that do the job and in each class I can use this function, or I need to implement the CompareTo function for each class
Thanks

```
Private Class A : Implements IComparable       
    Public A1 As String
    Public A2 As Integer
    Public Age As String

    Function CompareTo(ByVal obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        Dim a As A = CType(obj, A)
        Return String.Compare(CStr(Me.Age), CStr(a.Age))
    End Function
End Class

Private Class B : Implements IComparable
    Public B1 As String
    Public B2 As Date
    Public Age As String

    Function CompareTo(ByVal obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        Dim b As B = CType(obj, B)
        Return String.Compare(CStr(Me.Age), CStr(b.Age))
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Take a look on `IComparable` interface

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks for the quick reply, I looked, what I'm asking - if there is a possibility  to do it without the type name of the class (or receive the type name as parameter)

Comment: Maybe some sample of code will make your question more clear

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I added what I did,and my question more fluent....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the business need behind this code? If you elaborate, we may be able to suggest a better solution. Going too abstract is not always right for the case.

You could, however, create an Interface exposing `Age As String`, then implement an abstract class (MustInherit in VB), which will provide an implementation for this interface, then inherit your classes from the abstract class.

Comment: It is very good idea, I implemented my code as well , just made an abstract class which hold an operational params for the functions I needed

Comment: @user1249350: I am glad that it's working for you now. Feel free to tweak the solution, the above is only a general idea. If my answer was helpful, please accept/upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the somewhat sparse description of the problem, I believe that what you're looking to implement is a generic comparison method. The implementation is specific to what your requirements are. Again, based on your short description,  however, you'll need to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to cycle through the properties of TFrom and see whether or not TTo has the equivalent.

For your implementation, you have to answer a question simple question, "Are you doing this comparison to determine sort order?" If so, implementing the [IComparable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface as @Sergey Berezovskiy mentioned is the way to go. Otherwise, [IEquablable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a better choice.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, though I used Neolisk answer in my code